# Enclose command between two commands in python

Tags: python, function

I have two procedures in python called `A` and `B`.

The script Im trying to write imports those procedures and needs to run a list of commands (lets call them `C0`, `C1`, `C2`, etc.)

Those commands need to be enclosed by `A` and `B`
(Meaning: the script will look like this:

```
A(x)
C0
B(x)

A(x)
C1
B(x)

A(x)
C2
B(x)

.
.
.
```

(`x` is an argument passed to the procedure and its always the same)

How would you guys do this in a more pythonic, fast and elegant way?
Thanks!

Comment: `for C in list_of_commands:` / `A(x); C(); B(x)` perhaps?

Comment: I thought about making a list of command, but I was hoping for a different solution as this would make the code much harder to read since I would have many loops with many commands..
Also, its not super clear to me how to make a list of commands that can be run in the first place

Comment: If you do the same thing multiple times, define a function that does it and call the function multiple times.

Comment: It's not clear, given your question, why (from your comment) you would "have many loops with many commands". Can you clarify? A loop is clearly the right way to implement "doing the same thing over and over again".

Comment: How can you define a function that calls two functions with a custom command (thats always different) in between?

Comment: I would have many loops with many commands because the `x` in the question will not always be the same, so I would have to make different loops when I change the argument that I want to pass to `A` and `B`

Comment: It would help to _add_ some detail to your question, such as what `C0`, `C1`, etc. are supposed to be -- are these calls to some functions? Or are these placeholders for entire snippets of code?

Comment: They are indeed calls to functions.
For example `device.config.set(<data>)' where data is a numerical value. And I have many of those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple approach:

```
def sandwich(x, C, *args, **kwargs):
    A(x)
    C(*args, **kwargs)
    B(x)
```

Usage:

```
sandwich(x, C0)
sandwich(x, C1)
sandwich(x, C2)
sandwich(x, device.config.set, <data>) # if the call to wrap would be: device.config.set(<data>)
```

Comment: It's not clear to me how can you pass executable code to a function's argument.. sorry

Comment: @thyeme I don't understand what you mean. I have updated the answer to show how arguments can be provided to the function to call.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple context manager. Then you can use a `with` block to sandwich your logic between calls to `A` and `B`.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

def a(x):
    print(f"A {x}")

def b(x):
    print(f"B {x}")

@contextmanager
def ab():
    a("x")
    yield
    b("x")
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
with ab():
    print("1")


with ab():
    print("2")


with ab():
    print("3")
```

```
A x
1
B x
A x
2
B x
A x
3
B x
```

You could also combine that into a function wrapper so you can apply it to the command functions directly:

```
def ab_wrapper(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        with ab():
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@ab_wrapper
def C0():
    print("C0")

@ab_wrapper
def C1():
    print("C1")

@ab_wrapper
def C2():
    print("C2")

C0()
C1()
C2()
```

Comment: I like this idea. I can try to implement it like this.
Im wondering if there's a way to avoid calling `with ab():` for every command. Having something like `with ab():` and every following command already has a(x) and b(x) automatically

Comment: @thyeme see the wrapper example I added. If you don't want to touch the base library, you could do this at the start: `C0, C1, C2 = map(ab_wrapper, (C0, C1, C2))`. That will replace the definition with the wrapped version for the current module.

Comment: The tedious part I was trying to avoid is to write something extra every time Im calling a `C` command (I have many of those). With your wrapper method it doesnt seem like you wont do that, as you still need to define all of them beforehand, no?
Anyway, the wrapper way at least makes the code readable, as the commands are in a clear list eventually.

Comment: Yup. What your thinking of I'm imagining isn't possible unless you were to modify the actual python interpreter. This is as close as I can think of within the bounds of the language. Also, explicit is often a lot better than implicit.. especially when considering debugging and readability in the future. Take a look at `python -c 'import this'`